# system.web.mvc.htmlhelper does not contain a definition of content

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to create an asp.net MVC 3 Razor helper under app_code folder like this:

```
@using System.Web.Mvc;

@helper Script(string scriptName, System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper url){    
      <script src="@url.Content"~/Scripts/" + scriptName)" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
```

but I am getting error that:

system.web.mvc.htmlhelper does not contain a definition of content

at following line:

```
 <script src="@url.Content"~/Scripts/" + scriptName)" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is surprisingly helpful - HtmlHelper does not contains method Content(), the **UrlHelper** does. Try this :

```
@helper Script(string scriptName, System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper url){    
  <script src='@url.Content("~/Scripts/" + scriptName)' type="text/javascript"></script>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can to it like that but this is only avaliable in one view.

If you want to access this from other views you should write a real HtmlHelper like

**HtmlHelper sample**

Create static class

```
public static class TestClass
{
    public static IHtmlString Script(this HtmlHelper helper, string script)
    {
        // if you need the UrlHelper do this
        // var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(helper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
        return new HtmlString(string.Format("<script src=\"~/Scripts/{0}\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>", script));
    }
}
```

then you can call it from your view(s) like this

```
@Html.Script("jquery-1.5.1.js")
```

Make sure that you view knows the namespace where your class lives in too.

hope this helps

Comment: Hi: Thanks for the response. But what is issue with the code I posted. It is from video on asp.net MVC 3 website http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/players/PSODPlayer?author=scott-allen&name=mvc3-building-ajax&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-mvc3-intro

Comment: i updated my answer, maybe this helps you... i have a look at the video now

Comment: You can do it only the way you want inside one view. If you want to access from other views you should write a real HtmlHelper like in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but it's don't work for me.
After run all jQuery control don't work but in source i see it.

if i try to include

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

all controls working.